# Unable to iterate a list to a thread

Tags: pyqt5

I am trying to pass a json return between functions but I get errors. So I convert the json to a list. However, I cannot iterate the list from a while loop unless I specify an actual number.

Full code is

```
class BackendThread(QThread):
    update_date = pyqtSignal(list)

def run(self):
    device_mode = []
    while True:
        #do stuff and get json_return 

        for xx in json_return["result"]["devices"]:
            for y in xx["nodes"]:
                if y['type'] == "FRAME_BUFFER":
                    data = xx["device_id"] + "\n" + y['configuration']['display_mode'] 
                    device_mode.append(data)                                                
                    
        self.update_date.emit(str(device_mode))
        device_mode = []            
        time.sleep(1)        

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.resize(400,400)
        self.input=QTextEdit(self)
        self.input.resize(400,400)
    
        self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    self.backend=BackendThread()
    self.backend.update_date.connect(self.handleDisplay)
    self.backend.start()

def handleDisplay(self,data):
    count = 0
    while count < 11:
        self.input.setText(data[count])
        count += 1  
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win =Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So this part does not work. I only get the last item in the list

> ```
>  count = 0
>  while count < 11:
>      self.input.setText(data[count])
>      count += 1
> ```

When I do this, it works but I cannot hard code the item number becuase the list will never have the same amount of items

> ```
> self.input.setText(data[0]) 
> self.input.setText(data[1])
> self.input.setText(data[2])
> ```

etc

Any ideas as to how to get that while loop working?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to set the text as a string that concatenates the values of the list?

Comment: I want to display each element of the list in the text box which is about 400x400. For some reason the while loop will only display the last element as opposed to all 11 elements.

Comment: There's nothing obscure: in the while loop you're continuously *replacing* the text, that's what [`setText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setText) does: it *sets the text*. If you want to *append*, use [`append()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#append). Alternatively, use `setText('\n'.join(data))`. Besides, if you want to iterate through elements of a list, use `for item in data:`.